# user made GUI on booting of Rpi3

Tags: pi-3, boot, gui

I have a rpi 3 board. I am new to this field, I have a GUI developed in Visual studio on windows platform, i am able to run its .exe on Rpi board using mono, now i want to boot rpi such that it should not show anything but my GUI should start as soon as rpi boots. is there any way possible???? anything you can suggest for executing user made gui on boot of rpi, i have seen solutions for GUi developed in diffrent other languages, but in my case GUI is of .net framework and developed in windows.

Comment: you have not fully described your requirement ..... `show anything but my GUI` .... do you just want to show it? ... do you want it to be interactive?

Comment: I want GUI to be interactive as i have interfaced LCD touchpad monitor. i want this monitor should show GUI only. on booting GUI should be loaded by default nothing else.

Comment: `GUI should be loaded by default nothing else` .... that sounds like you are saying that the GUI program is actually the operating system .... is that correct?

Comment: jsotola actually GUI is not OS, buit is there any way that my GUI should appear on Rpi screen before its desktop GUI appears and end user should be able to access only my GUI nothing else. is there any way to do that???

Comment: You're looking for *kiosk-mode* see some of those https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiosk to narrow and specify this question.